# Return Hex values from C Dll to Python using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, dll, hex, ctypes

I have a large array in a file that I cannot modify but need to access in C++. I need to iterate through the array and return a value to a python script.

Problem: I am able to find the element in the array by it's name. When I try to return it's value and section elements to the python wrapper they return 0 or -1 no matter what their actual value is. Here is an example of the first element in the array from external_lists.h :

```
info_struct A1[] = {
{ "LIMITING", {{0x00, 0x02, 0xFF}}
 .........
    }
```

This array has thousands of similar elements. When I run the following code I get `0x` or `-0x1`. Valuedll.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include "external_lists.h"

extern info_struct A1[];
extern info_struct  A2[];
extern int A1size;
extern int A2size;

#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DLLEXPORT int get_creation_data(const char* needed_name){

int A1_size = ( A1size/ sizeof(A1[0])) ;
int A2_size = ( A2size / sizeof(A2[0]))  ;

for (int i = 0; i < A1_size; i++) {
    if (A1[i].name == needed_name) { 
    return A1[i].style->value; 
    }
  }
    return -1;
}
```

The type `info_struct` is made from the following struct:

```
struct info_struct{
const char* name; 
style_length style[MAX_SIZE];
options_length options[MAX_SIZE];
}
```

I need to get the values that are inside the style array. The style_length struct is the following:

```
struct style_length{
   uint16_t value, section;
   option_bits obits;
}
```

My python wrapper is the following:

```
import os, sys, re
from ctypes import *
import ctypes as ct

def get_creation_values(value_name):
  valuell = CDLL('C:\\Documents\\creation.dll')
  valuell.get_section_data.argtypes = [c_char_p]
  valuell.get_section_data.restype = ct.c_int16
  return hex(valuell.get_creation_data(value_name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  val = get_creation_values('LIMITING')
  print(val)
```

Output:

```
(-0x1)
```

Thanks in advance for any help. If this is too much, thank you for reading. I will try to clarify.

Comment: I don't see how it explains your problem, but the function returns `int` so the `restype` shoudl be `ct.c_int`. Also, which version of python are you using? In playing with this, my `c_int16` types print as `c_short(-1)` not `-0x1`.

Comment: First, you don't have "hex values", you have int values. Those values can be represented in hex, decimal, octal, or binary, but they're still the same values. Second, C `int` isn't the same type as ctypes `c_int16` unless you're on a platform with 16-bit integers, and you're obviously not (Win32 doesn't run on any such platforms).

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `needed_name` is? Normally python only uses wchar_t*, and I don't think ctypes will do the conversion from 16bit encoded string to 8bit. So maybe you change your string type in your funcion declaration to wchar_t* and in your struct, if that's an option.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (strcmp(A1[i].name, needed_name) == 0)`?

Comment: @thejinx0r - ctypes does `char_t*` as well as `wchar_t*`. In python 3 you have to do a .encode() on your string. I took this and other artifacts as a hint that user is on 2.x. Unfortunately user hasn't let us know.

Comment: The string comparison is comparing pointers. Needs to use strcmp.

Comment: @tdelaney I am using 2.7 sorry. And with strcmp, it still will return the default -1 value or 0, even if it finds the correct name and it's corresponding style member is not set to 0. I tested to see if it was in fact finding the strings with outputting and it did. I also had my restypes in python and thedll method as returning 16bit ints and switched it to ints if I could find some method. No matter what, It still does not return the correct value but just 0.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I did use strcmp, which worked to find the matching strings but the style member variable will always return -1 or 0 even if the value is not 0.

Comment: @abarnert thank you, I learned something new. I was just trying to match the return type with the variable I was trying to access, hoping that would help me get the right value. So what do you think I should do?

Comment: It would be easiest to help if the DLL code was a self-contained example and when compiled worked with the Python example code so we could reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yeah I apologize it really isn't self-contained. The external_lists.h file is one of many files within several projects and it's not easy to sort out. I pretty much can't modify anything except my dll I'm making or the python script.

Comment: But you DLL can skip importing the external_lists.h file and hard-code a short array example instead.  There's no obvious error in the example we have, so if we can't reproduce it, it is difficult to help.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I took a suggested edit which explained my error more but after investigating more. It is an error within the layers of structs that make up the info_struct object so I had to point to something else to get my value and it worked to return the correct value now. I really appreciate all of your help, it gave me a different viewpoint.